# Does cancellation impact vertical asymptotes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

Question: Let $r(x) = \frac{(x^2 + x)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)}$. Does the graph has $x = 1$ as one of its asymptotes?

Answer: No.

My reasoning: $\frac{(x^2 + x)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)} = \frac{x(x + 1)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)} = \frac{x}{(2x - 4)}$ and so, it cannot have $x=-1$ as one of its asymptotes.

*However*, what if I don't calcel and then say that $-1$ is a vertical asymptote? Will I be wrong?

Comment: Having something in denominator doesn't mean that it has to be a vertical asymptote. Being unbound when the argument tends to some value does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct saying that the function 
$$
r(x) = \frac{(x^2 + x)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)}
$$
has not an asymptote for $x=-1$ since:
$$
\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{(x^2 + x)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)}=\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{x(x + 1)}{(x + 1)(2x - 4)}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

but this function is not defined for $x=-1$ so its graph has an ''hole'' at the point $(-1 ,\frac{1}{6})$ and the functios is not the same as
$$
y=\frac{x}{(2x - 4)}
$$

Comment: Then how come it has an asymptote of 2? The function shouldn't be defined at 2 either, but it does have an asymptote there.

Comment: Yes. The function is not defined for $x=2$ and here the limit is $\pm \infty$ so we have a vertical asymptote.